# Saving email contacts in contact folder in MS Outlook 2007

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, contacts

I have an email sent by me in my Sent Items folder. That email has more than 50 email addresses (recipients). I now want to save all those email addresses and IDs in my contact list so that I can use them in future.

How do I go about doing this in Outlook 2007?

Comment: Posting the same question twice will not get an answer sooner. A response sometimes takes a bit of time.

Answer (score 0):

By far the easiest way to do this is to save the email as a text file.  Strip out the heading, leaving just the names and emails.

Open up Access.  If you don't have Access, then Excel should do.  Import the text file and use space delimited as your option.  Don't worry if it splits names too many times.  It's easier to combine columns than it is to split them.

Make a heading for each column, like `First Name`.

Scroll through and make sure it all looks correct.  Then save the file as either a CSV(comma spaced values) or a Tab delimited file.  Either should do.  Outlook is pretty good at reading them.

Open up Outlook and import the files using the wizard.  At the very last step, there should be a button that says something like "Map custom fields."

Click that and look at how Outlook is reading each column heading and placing those values into a certain contact field.  Make sure they match up and then hit finished.